# How to use += operator on formula field?

Tags: formula, auto-number

On Delivery note Line Item , I have the field Delivered_Quantity__c ( number type ) and , I 'd like to record the total number of this field for each items .
So the idea is I create a new field called (Total Delivered ) which is the sum of Delivered Quantity for all delivery notes .

the formula is like this :

> Total Delivered += Delivered_Quantity__c

do you know how to do that when we enter formula ??

I tried but error

> += Delivered_Quantity__c

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new custom field on your Delivery note of the type Roll-Up Summary.

That field displays the sum, minimum, or maximum value of a field in a related list or the record count of all records listed in a related list.

See: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm

Comment: yes , but the problem is  the type roll-um summary concern the total of Delivery note ( for all Items ) . if we have 3 items : Item 1 , Item 2  and Item 3 I would like to know how many we are already delivered for the Item 1 . the same thing for Item 2  etc ... for all Delivery notes

Comment: How many different items do you have? If it is only a few, than you could create a roll up summary for each. You can then filter each roll up summary for the specific item.  If you have many, then it depends on your use case. Maybe a raport would work better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to do exactly, but I think you want to sum only certain items and not all items. Anyway, you cannot achieve that with a formula field. You have two options here: a rollup-summary field on the master object, or a trigger that updates a custom field on the master object each time there is an insert/update/delete in the child object. But in most cases, a roll-up summary should be sufficient.

Comment: Hi , I mean if we have a rollup summary field  based on Delivered_Quantity on parent ( Sales Order ) the result is total delivered for all Items (Item 1 , Item 2 , Item 3 ) . My question is : it is possible to use a rollup summary field for each rows ???

Comment: Can you explain more please? What do you mean by "it is possible to use a rollup summary field for each rows ?". Can you give a simple example with numbers so we can help you? Thanks.

Comment: Hi , please , you can find the link  http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=15/29/2w01.png   just to make it clear .

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there a master-detail relationship between Sales Order Line Items (parent) and Delivery Notes (child)? If yes, easy, you make a rollup summary field on the parent object (Sales Order Line Item).

If not, you have to write an Apex Trigger.  Each time you insert, update or delete a Delivery Note object, your trigger looks for a corresponding item in Sales Order Line Items and does the appropriate calculation. If you're a developer, I guess that might be easy for you. If not, you will have to get in touch with a developer and get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

just create a roll up summary field and specify condition i.e., Sum of the field and condition is status is delivered like , it will give you only delivered items total ...you can see my screen as below: 
[image]